# Mongodb .Net driver Find case insensitive

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Given the following JSON, I'm trying to get all documents that match "myemail@domain.com". I need a case insensitive filter. I thought if I added i to the value it would perform the search but no luck.

I'm very new to MongoDB so excuse me if this is a simple issue.

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5aecc56d2a7e7a408c9767e3"),     
"Children" : [
    {
        "Email" : "MyEmail@Domain.com", 
        "Children" : [
            {
                "Name" : "Some name", 
                "Value" : "some value",                     
            }
        ]
    }
]
}

var email = "myemail@domain.com";
var filter = Builders<Subscription>.Filter.Eq("Children.Email", $"/{email}/i");
return await context.Subscriptions.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a dedicated class `BsonRegularExpression` which can be used as a parameter of `Regex` method. Simple `Eq` will try to perform regular equality comparison here. Try this:

```
var email = "myemail@domain.com";
var filter = Builders<Subscription>.Filter.Regex("Children.Email", new BsonRegularExpression(email, "i"));
return await context.Subscriptions.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```